# Getters in Redux's actions - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I would like to have functions that can get the current state to do some logic with it, without having to pass the current state via parameters to the function.

Here is my example.

In my action file, I have:

```
export const addToSearchHistory = (newSearch) => ({type: ADD_TO_SEARCH_HISTORY, newSearch})
export const addToCardHistory = (newCard) => ({type: ADD_TO_CARD_HISTORY, newCard})
```

And for example I would like to have a "getter" function that tells me if the "Search history" has hit 10 items. So what I did is:

```
export const searchHasMaxHistory = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  var state = getState()
      search = state.search

  return search.history == 10 ? true : false
}
```

And I bind this function with the other "real" actions with bindActionCreators:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    addToSearchHistory,
    addToCardHistory,

    searchHasMaxHistory
  }, dispatch)
}
```

So I'll be accessible as any normal actions. It works well and does exactly what I want.

But the real question is, is it anti-pattern to bind it like an action but it doesn't return an action? May I run into issues or whatsoever by doing that? And is there a "right" solution to do that?

Comment: mapDispatchToProps wraps your functions in dispatch calls. If your action creator (searchHasMaxHistory) will "return search.history == 10 ? true : false", then that return value will be dispatched. Dispatch is only meant to dispatch an action (plain object), which will change the state of your application. In this case it won't because none of your reducers handle an action: bool(true/false)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this, you should bind your "getter" (which is described as a "selector" in [the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#remarks)) to your component via the `mapStateToProps` function.

```
// the selector (probably in your reducer file)

export const searchHasMaxHistory = state => {
  return state.search.history == 10 ? true : false
}

// in your component

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    hasHitMaxHistory: searchHasMaxHistory(state)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ... // keep the same, remove your "getter"

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YourComponent)
```

This approach makes more sense to me, as your component's new prop will behave as intended, and trigger a render() when the returned value changes.

Comment: Yep I heard about the "selectors", however it doesn't refresh when the state changes. It seems it should have :/

Comment: Lol my bad it didn't refresh because I've made other changes and it wasn't "linked" anymore... Thanks! Your answer seemed the best because you talked about selectors and that's the way to go if you want getters-like functions with Redux :)

Comment: You're welcome! That part of react-redux is that one thing that can feel a bit too magic sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) of `connect()`

> mapStateToProps(state): (Function): If specified, the component will subscribe to Redux store updates. Any time it updates, mapStateToProps will be called

So you could write your `connect()` clause like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    searchHasMaxHistory: state.search.history === 10
  };
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

But of course, that would calculate your new value on every store change. You might not want that. In that case you could define a separate function and bind your state to it on each store (state) change.

```
function isMaxHistoryReached(state) {
  return state.search.history === 10;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    searchHasMaxHistory: isMaxHistoryReached.bind(YourComponent, state)
  };
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

Now that still creates a new function in memory on each state change, but it won't call it.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you goal is:

> I would like to have functions that can get the current state to do
>   some logic with it, without having to pass the current state via
>   parameters to the function.

But [`bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) is for another purpose.

It wraps all you action creators with a [`dispatch`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) call so they may be invoked directly.

We doing things in a hackish way, instead why not we use the original `store` object to get the state.

Create a getter for your `store` object where you `createStore`.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducer';

let store = {};

export default function storeCreator () {
    // ...do things

    store = createStore(reducer);

    // ...do more things

    return store;  
}

export function getStore() {
    return store;
}
```

Now inside your **state-getter**:

```
import { getStore } from './storeCreator';

export function searchHasMaxHistory() {
  const store = getStore();
  const state = store.getState();
  const search = state.search;

  return search.history == 10 ? true : false
}
```

Comment: Now that is an anti-pattern. You're creating a store singleton. If you create store more than once (not that you would), you will overwrite your "store" variable and getStore() will always give you the latest singleton. In which case you wouldn't need storeCreator() nor getStore(). Just write "export default createStore(reducer)" and each "import" gives you the same store instance.